# HapiJs routes access base on role

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am using the HapiJs at server side and want to do route configuration base on role, I want to restrict user to access some end points

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 8000 });

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'api1',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply('Hello, world!');
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'api2',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply('Hello');
  }
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'api3',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply('Hello');
  }
});

const parseHeader = (request, h) => {
   const { role } = JSON.parse(request.headers["roles"]);

};

server.ext("onRequest", parseHeader);

server.start(function () {
  console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

Here I am getting the role from roles header so roles could be "admin" or "customer". If role is admin user can access all api end points 'api1', 'api2' and 'api3' but if its "customer" then only 'api3' could be accesible.

How to achieve this kind of authorization on routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create "middleware" - pre handler that will check user's role , 
if user's role is admin , then continue else deny access

```
var Boom = require('boom');


const CheckAdmin= function (request, reply) {
    const { role } = JSON.parse(request.headers["roles"]);
    if(role=='admin'){
       return reply.continue();
    }else{
       return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Access Denied'));
    }
}



 server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: 'api1',
    config: {
         pre: [{ method: CheckAdmin }],
         handler: function (request, reply) {
         reply('Hello, world!');
    }
  });

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'api2',
  config: {
         pre: [{ method: CheckAdmin }],
         handler: function (request, reply) {
         reply('Hello, world!');
    }
});
```

// api3 is open , all can use that , so no need to add pre handler here

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'api3',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    reply('Hello');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

hapi.js has a default mechanism for that. It's called [auth scope](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#route.options.auth.access.scope).

Define your route's auth config with scope field

```
exports.userList = {
    description: 'list users',
    auth: {
        scope: ['admin]
    },    
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        // .. your code here
    }
};
```

This says, only the user in the admin scope may access to this route.

Then in your authentication code add scope field to your credentials object.

```
exports.plugin = {
    async register(server, options) {
        const implementation = function (server, options) {

            return {
                authenticate: function (request, h) {

                    // check user here
                    const user = findInDbOrSomething();
                    if (!user) {                        
                        // redirect user to login page
                        return h.redirect('/auth/login').takeover()
                    }

                    credentials = {
                        name: user.name,
                        email: user.email,
                        scope: ["admin"] // or user.scope if user has a scope field or get it from somewhere else
                    }

                    return h.authenticated({credentials});
                }
            }
        };
        server.auth.scheme('basic', implementation);
        server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic');
        server.auth.default('simple')
    },
    name: 'auth',
    version: require('../package.json').version
};
```